# How to add a new dropdown-value to a Magento SEO-list?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 and I want to set a different value for the meta-robots-tag for several products. Therefore I go to Catalog > Article > Meta Information > And select a value from the dropdown "Robots Meta Tag"

Now comes the problem. I just have 4 selectable values in this dropdown, like this:

```
<select id="seo_meta_robots" name="product[seo_meta_robots]" class=" select">
    <option value="0">Don't change</option>
    <option value="1">NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW</option>
    <option value="2">NOINDEX, FOLLOW</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">INDEX, NOFOLLOW</option>
</select>
```

And I'd need a 5th one, labeled "index,follow" - how/where would I need to add that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easier way would be to copy this file `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Source/Design/Robots.php` into `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Source/Design/Robots.php` and add the option there:

```
public function toOptionArray()
{
    return array(
        array('value'=>'INDEX,FOLLOW', 'label'=>'INDEX, FOLLOW'),
        array('value'=>'NOINDEX,FOLLOW', 'label'=>'NOINDEX, FOLLOW'),
        array('value'=>'INDEX,NOFOLLOW', 'label'=>'INDEX, NOFOLLOW'),
        array('value'=>'NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW', 'label'=>'NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW'),
        array('value'=>'INDEX,FOLLOW', 'label'=>'INDEX, FOLLOW'),
    );
}
```

However, the best practise would be creating a Magento Extension and overriding this model to add the option. Since it's a one line code change it probably doesn't worth the effort though, but bear in mind that you might need to maintain changes on this file if you ever upgrade Magento (it's unlikely that this file will be changed).

I hope it helps!